# Common time formats represented in python

Tags: python, time

I am writing a time parser and I was wondering if there are any common representations of calendar time than the following default format:

```
# 12:13:14 PM (FORMAT_TIME)
"%H:%M:%S %p",
```

What would be other possible ways to represent time that are commonly used in the real (non-scientific/cs) world?

I suppose some patterns could be:

```
12:13:14 # (no am/pm) -- %H:%M%S
```

Or:

```
12:13:14.123 # (fractional seconds) -- %H:%M%S.%f
```

Or:

```
12:13:14.123 PM # (fractional seconds) -- %H:%M%S.%f %p
```

Or:

```
12:13 # (no seconds, no am/pm) -- %H:%M
```

Or:

```
12:13 PM # (no seconds) -- %H:%M %p
```

Though I feel like the above three patterns would be infreqnently used. Are there any common patterns that may be used to show time?

Comment: The pattern used to show time is also somewhat locale dependent I'm sure.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the Python standard `time` library for information about Python time formats:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#module-time

An important one you may be missing for computational reasons is *seconds since epoch*, however as you said this is for "real world" representation this may not matter.

Answer (score 0):

Consider 24-hour times, different separators (dot, '.', being common in parts of Europe). With /without leading zeros on the hour. Optional space before 'AM/PM', lower case (am/pm). A French convention you may see is %H h %M. For example `18 h 45` == 6:45pm

Answer (score 0):

[ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Times) seems like a worthy standard to support, and it has a few interesting things to think about:

- Basic time format allows no colons (164100 could map to 16:41:00); extended format uses colons as separators
- Midnight can be rendered as 24:00 in addition to 00:00
- Fractions are possible, but only on the lowest significant digit; separators can either be a comma or a period

Also, would you ever need to handle time zone identifiers? If so, that's a big can of worms.

I would argue that you shouldn't reinvent the wheel and use a battle tested library to do this kind of thing (unless you're simply doing it for fun).